# Azure Function App connected to database not working

Tags: azure, sqlclient

I am relatively new to all this and I have followed several tutorials to be able to carry out the objective of my title, but I can't get it to work. For example, I followed this tutorial:
https://www.sqlshack.com/azure-functions-for-azure-sql-database/

and in all the tutorials that I see, things work, but in my case it doesn't.

All the errors I get have to do with the reference to "System.Data.SqlClient"

```
error CS1069: The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

From what I understand, it's because of the missing NuGet package, but I have no idea how to integrate it into the Azure portal, also, from what I understand, it should be integrated automatically.
What can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Azure function doesn't really provide seamless support for installation of the Nuget packages if the function is developed using portal
- So I would suggest you use visual Studio where you can easily install nuget packages through the inbuild support for the package manager in the visual studio
- To do this once you have created the basic function in visual studio go under `tools` tab then under the `NuGet Package Manager` option click on `Manage NuGet Pacakges for Solution`.

[image]

- This will open a new window where you can search on the package manager . Just search for `System.Data.SqlClient` in the window select the name of the project and install .

[image]

- Here my code checks whether the connection is established or not

```
string connstring = "";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
conn.Open();
if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    return new OkObjectResult("Connected");
}            
conn.Close();
return new OkObjectResult("Waiting");
```

- Now we can deploy the function from visual studio to azure by right clicking on the name of the project in the solution explore and select `publish`

[image]

The a pop will appear where you have to select the type of function app and then either create a function app or select the existing ones then deploy.

[image]

- Another approach would be to upload a `function.proj` file which will have reference to the NuGet package . Refer this [tutorial](https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2019/08/adding-nuget-packages-to-azure.html) for it which is written by Hasan Savran